# How can I add variable name and value from `str` to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that I'm gonna write more variables to. I successfully use the information in it, and change information in it, but I can't find a way to make new variables. I want to use `c` in `add_unit_group()` to define both name of the new variable, and its list. I have tried using `c` to only define the name of the variable as well, but with no luck.

To the `UnitGroups` class, I want to add: `a2 = ("default", unit_type)`

```
import units

unit_type = (units.Tank1, units.Tank2, units.Tank3, units.Infantry1, units.Infantry2)

class UnitGroups:
    a = "empty"
    a1 = ("default", unit_type)
    create = "1"

def addunitgroup():
    add = ("default", unit_type)
    # UnitGroups.create = add
    for make in range(0, 10):
        if make is int(UnitGroups.create):
            print(def_name, ":   ", "make is UnitGroups.create")
            generate = UnitGroups()
        
            a = (int(UnitGroups.create) + 1)
            b = "a" + str(a)
            c = str("generate." + b + " = " + str(add))

            # UnitGroups.a = (c, " = ", str(add))
            # exec(str(UnitGroups.a))
            # UnitGroups.a2 = add
          
            UnitGroups.create = (int(UnitGroups.create) + 1)
            UnitGroups.a = "empty"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addunitgroup()
```

I do not want to change the format. The variables shall be stored in that class.

Outcome that I want after first use of "addunitgroup()"

```
class UnitGroups:
    a = "empty"
    a1 = ("default", unit_type)
    a2 = ("default", unit_type)
    create = "2"
```

Outcome that I want after second use of "addunitgroup()"

```
class UnitGroups:
    a = "empty"
    a1 = ("default", unit_type)
    a2 = ("default", unit_type)
    a3 = ("default", unit_type)
    create = "3"
```

More information, just to show how I currently change the variables inside the class. I don't need help with what's added now:
This `load()` function will change, and will also set the variables' values depending on what a file tells it to. I'll also use another function to set the values of the variables. This one will be run from a window.

```
def load():
    UnitGroups.a1 = ("5", units.Tank1)
```

Comment: Make it a class variable?

Comment: The lsat comment represents a way to add a new variable to UnitGroups, but does not work when addunitgroup() is run more times, as of that I then want: a3, a4, a5...

Comment: By any chance looking for `setattr (object, varNameAsAString, value)`?

Comment: @Anderas I'm not exactly sure what your saying, but perhaps you want to make a variable which is an attribute of your class. Via `self.varname = value`.

Comment: Seems  you need a list, `a[3]`, `a[4]` etc. Or, if you really want `a3`, `a4` etc, use 'setattr' as I described.

Comment: I'll edit the question to add wanted outcome after the use addunitgroup() two times.

Comment: Yes, I believe you want what @JacquesdeHoogen is saying.

Comment: Advice: Just use an list, 'setattr' will do what you want, but its pointless and   hackish. I see some other suspicious things in your code, like using class- rather than instance attributes. Perhaps it's a good idea to follow an online tutorial first, like https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes Take good notice of the difference between classes and instances.

Comment: I have never used "setattr" before. I will look into it, but I'm not sure if it gives me what I want.

Comment: I mean: don't use setattr, just use a list...

Comment: Why shouldn't I use "setattr", @JacquesdeHooge ?

Comment: @Andreas: It works, but usually (this is not python-specific) classes are supposed to have pre-defined attributes, and use them to provide services to other classes. If you want a container of `name=value` pairs you should probably use a data structure (a `dict` in python), instead of a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setattr(instance, variable_name, variable_value)`

Btw: the way you have defined your class, the variables belong to the class itself, not the instance (roughly like static variables in other languages)

Comment: because he has the variable name as string, so he can't use the dot notation

Comment: @leaf: here: "The lsat comment represents a way to add a new variable to UnitGroups, but does not work when addunitgroup() is run more times, as of that I then want: a3, a4, a5... – ". If this has to be done an arbitrary number of times, the only thing to do is generate varnames automatically as strings. But I think all he needs is a list, really (and a good tutorial).

Comment: @blue_note Alright, I see what you were referring to now. My apologies for not looking in the comments.

Comment: @Andreas: ok, still `setattr` creates the attribute. however, if  you want to treat the class as arbitrary key-value pairs, you should use a `dict` instead

Comment: I am now using "setattr" to create new variables. For every time the function is run, it creates a new variable, and adds 1 to "UnitGroups.create", which is used to determine the name of new variables. I have also changed more of the function as well, including removing "UnitGroups.a". This works very well.

Comment: And yes, I am learning Python. I didn't know about the attribute functions when this question was made. Why would it be a problem using "setattr"?

Answer (score 0):

```
class B:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.a = []

    def add (self, value)
        self.a.append (value)

b = B ()       # Constructor __init__ calles, will make empty list inside b
b.add ('john') # Will be in b.a [0]
b.add ('mary') # Will be in b.a [1]

b2 = B ()      # Another instance, to hold different names
b.add ('bjarne') # Will be in b2.a [0]
b.add ('guido')  # Will be in b2.a [1]
```

etc.

Comment: It's just a start. Be sure to read https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes for the rest.